# Find user-control's control from another user-control in same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an `usercontrol` that has `treeview` inside.
Now I have placed it in an `aspx page` twice with some different `Id` let us say `usercontrolA` and `usercontrolB`.
Both of them are loaded in to page one by one.
Now in `pre-render event` of `usercontrolA` I want to get the object of `treeview` control of `usercontrolB`.
 How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the *instance* of `usercontrolB` to access the `treeview` control for both the user controls. So try *preserving* the instance in some appropriate storage to access it in the `pre-render` event.

1. Introduce a property to hold the UC Type inside the `User-Control`:

   ```
   public MyUserControl MainUserControl { get; set; }
   ```
2. In the parent ASPX set the property with `usercontrolB`:

   ```
   usercontrolA.MainUserControl = usercontrolB;
   usercontrolB.MainUserControl = usercontrolB;
   ```
3. Now you can use the `MainUserControl` property to access your `TreeView`:

   ```
   MainUserControl.treeView1 ...
   ```

Comment: yes I know, if I do it like find the usercontrol from its parent page and then find treeview from it. Isn't there any way to find it direct easily?

Comment: Since your requirement is to access the treeview of usercontrolB in both the user controls so there is no direct way to access treeview. You have to preserve the instance of usercontrolB before accessing the treeview.

Comment: OK. Thanks, but I will wait for direct solution. If I won't get it then follow this and also will mark the answer as accepted with upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried a lot but in last I found only this way easy and useful. Thanks. :)

Comment: @FSX Should i introduce a property for both user-controls?
Where should i set the property in the parent ASPX?

Comment: @Amir, The User-Control is same for both the instances so you just need to introduce (one place) the property in it. And in the parent you can set the property in say Load event handler.

Answer (score 2):

This example for finding a "usercontrolB" named treeview on any control on this form.

```
            Control[] ctrl = this.Controls.Find("usercontrolB", true);
            if (ctrl != null && ctrl.Length > 0)
            {
                TreeView tv = (TreeView)ctrl[0];
                // do whatever you want with the treeview
            }
```

Comment: I want to access it from usercontrol, not page. I don't have an usercontrol inside usercontrol, So in prerender event of usercontrol it self how can I find usercontrolB?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand it. Hope somebody can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to access it in PreRender?

You'd need to create a custom event:

**Main Page**

```
var uc1 = (UserControlType1)LoadControl("UC1.ascx");
var uc2 = (UserControlType1)LoadControl("UC2.ascx");
uc2.PreRendered += uc2_PreRendered;

public void uc2_PreRendered(object sender, TreeView tv){
    // you can access your treeview from here
}
```

**User Control B**

```
public delegate void PreRenderDelegate(object sender, TreeView tv);
public event PreRenderDelegate PreRender;

public void OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(this.Prerendered!=null)
        this.Prerendered(this, aTreeView);
}
```

Comment: uc2.PreRendered += uc2_PreRendered; is giving me error "No overload for 'uc2_PreRender' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: @Dev I think `uc2.PreRendered` should be `uc2.PreRender` which would match the event in the User Control B code.

Comment: You just need to create a custom event in your second UserControl (with the TreeView), then subscribe to the event on the page. When the event is called, you pass the TreeView to your first UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can the use the following code in your user-controlA's `OnPreRender` event:

```
var tree = this.Page.FindControl("uc2").FindControl("treeview1");
```

**Note:** "uc2" is User-ControlB's ID in ASPX page.

Or you can try this:

```
 var tree = this.Page.LoadControl("UserControlB.ascx").FindControl("treeview1");
```

Comment: I want it in usercontrol itself man. I want to get the user control's treeview in prerender event of usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

(I am just re-posting [my post that helped](http://forums.asp.net/post/5252125.aspx) for others to refer)

You can always update the RadTreeView using the events for controls by passing some values as property and calling the databind method for your RadTree (the one in your user control) again ... that being said you can pass the object of the RadTree itself, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var str=This.Page.findControl("UserControlName").FindControl("NameOfTheControlToFind")
```