# c# XAML Access UserControl from other UserControl on same page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Similar question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054959/find-user-controls-control-from-another-user-control-in-same-page). The difference is that I have the following structure for my Page-UserControl1-UserControl2:

On the Page I have a ListBox with several ListBoxItems whith each Item is based on the UserControl1. The UserControl is also based on the same Page but there is only one instance of it.

As I linked the other thread, I can't do the following:

I introduced a property at the top of Control1 code-behind:

```
 public Control2 ctrl2 { get; set; }
```

And then I gave the Control2 a name in the xaml file of the Page:

```
<local:Control2 Grid.Row="2" x:Name="NameOfControl2"></local:Control2>
```

The next step I would like to do is to pass the instance of Control2 to the property just set in Control1. So in the OnLoad Method in the code-behind of the  Page I want to do the following which cant work because the instance of Control1 is unknown at this point:

```
Control1.ctrl2 = NameOfControl;
```

With that doing I could access my UserControl2 from each insatance of UserControl1 but how do I do this?

Thanks

**//IN RESPONSE TO THE COMMENT FROM AMINE:**

this is the xaml of the Page:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 5"       
            x:Name = "Box"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1 x:Name="NameOfControl1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Box,Path=DataContext}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

And in the code-behind I fill the Items with:

```
            StandardTweetBox.Items?.Add(MySpecialClass);
            //this.DataContext = NameOfSendControl;
            StandardTweetBox.DataContext = NameOfSendControl;
```

Comment: Have you tried to navigate via Parent or Child(ren) properties. Why do you need to access those controls? Are you using MVVM pattern? Helpful tool could be visual tree helper: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Comment: In the Init() of the UserControl1 I've tried: `var obj = this.Parent;` but the value returned is null. So I assume I have no chance to get to the parent. 
Yes, I'm using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: If you are using MVVM; why you don't share one ViewModel between usercontrols?

Comment: On the page code-behind I've also get null in return for `IEnumerable<Control1> collection = LayoutRoot.Children.OfType<Control1>();`

Comment: @Amine Because i dont know how to do it. I would prefer it doing it somewhere around to prevent me explaining all the stuff I did so far.
But sure... if this the way to do it I will try to explain

Comment: I can show you how to use one viewmodel but I don't know if it will be helpful for you

Comment: @Amine please look at the updated question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok. I've added another property to my SpecialClass and passed it to the `Tag` of the root node (Grid) of UserControl1. This is working. So thx Amine for that. But this doesnt looks pretty because this "new" property of type 'UserControl2' clearly has nothing in common with this class. I could make it a static member of that class but doesn't make sense as well

Comment: Did you see my answer. Is that can help you?

Comment: @Amine Yes, thx. just trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109568/discussion-between-ulpin-and-amine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MainPage code-behind put:

```
this.DataContext = new YourViewModel();
Box.DataContext = this.DataContext;
```

And replace your xaml by this :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 5"       
            x:Name = "Box"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControl1 x:Name="ctrl1name" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Box,Path=DataContext}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And

```
<local:Control2 Grid.Row="2" x:Name="NameOfControl2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Box,Path=DataContext}"></local:Control2>
```

Now, the mainpage,usercontrl1 and usercontrl2 will have the same ViewModel

Comment: I've done it. But doing as you said I destroyed somehow my "old" viewmodel. It's like I've overriden it. I did the following:
In the OnLoad of the Page when my SpecialClass is already bound to the ListBoxItems I did: `this.DataContext = NameControl2;
            Box.DataContext = this.DataContext;`
Is it right that I have to store my specialClass in this DataContext as well? But how?

Comment: why you set this.DataContext = NameControl2? can you share your xaml and cs code of the MainPage?

Comment: Updated the question. Of course, this line of code was pure nonsense so I've commented it out

Comment: @Ulpin the DataContext of your MainPage must be an instance of your MainViewModel. And you bind all DataContext of your UserControls to the MainPage DataContext.
What's the name of your MainViewModel?

Comment: Ok. I think I know would you mean and I also think I've never used this MainViewModel. Code looks like this:

` private readonly ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }`
So is it right I have to store all my Data in this Observable Collection? BTW: this App is based on a HupPage Template for WindowsPhone

Comment: @Ulpin look at this sample project. It will help you to understand https://github.com/AmineKhiyat/WPF_OneViewModel_MultiView

Comment: Thx. I understand this example but not sure how to transfer it to my project. Dont know how to handle my SpecialClass in combination with the instance of the UserControl2. Do I have to put them together in this MainViewModel? Is it correct that I can use this Obseravable Collection to put them together?

Comment: @Ulpin can you share all your code. It will be easy to help you

Comment: Sure. let me try one thing and I'll post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109570/discussion-between-ulpin-and-amine).